# why my logger doesn't log file with using data_ingestion file?

Tags: logging

I am following some courses on youtube.One of them is mlops. I try to log (using logging) specific messages so I create a logger.py. But when I create a file (data_ingestion.py) which calls logger, directory are created empty (witout any logfiles). I don't know why with the data_ingestion.py it doesn't work!! Help is needed :( thanks a lot

ps: logger.py is ./src/ directory and data_ingestion.py is ./src/components/ directory

logger.py

```
`import logging
import os
from datetime import datetime

LOG_FILE=f"{datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')}.log"
logs_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"logs",LOG_FILE)
os.makedirs(logs_path,exist_ok=True)

LOG_FILE_PATH=os.path.join(logs_path,LOG_FILE)

logging.basicConfig(
    filename=LOG_FILE_PATH,
    format="[ %(asctime)s ] %(lineno)d %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
    level=logging.INFO,


)`
```

data_ingestion.py

```
`import os
import sys
from src.exception import CustomException

from src.logger import logging
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from dataclasses import dataclass



@dataclass
class DataIngestionConfig:
    train_data_path:str=os.path.join("artefacts","train.csv")
    test_data_path:str=os.path.join("artefacts","test.csv")
    raw_data_path:str=os.path.join("artefacts","data.csv")

class DataIngestion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ingestion_config=DataIngestionConfig()

    def iniate_data_ingestion(self):
        logging.info("Activation des données")
        try:
            df=pd.read_csv('notebook\data\stud.csv')
            logging.info('Lecture des données en Dataframe')
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path),exist_ok=True)

            df.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.raw_data_path, index=False,header=True)
        
            logging.info("Séparation en jeu d'entrainement et de test initiée")

            train_set,test_test=train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
        
            train_set.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.train_data_path, index=False,header=True)
            test_test.to_csv(self.ingestion_config.test_data_path, index=False,header=True)

            logging.info("Les données ont toute été rentrée")
        
            return (
                self.ingestion_config.train_data_path,
                self.ingestion_config.test_data_path
                )
        
        except Exception as e:
            raise CustomException(e,sys)

if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=DataIngestion()
    obj.iniate_data_ingestion()`
```

If I use a small code, just:

```
`from loggger import logging
logging.info("42")`
```

it works: a directory AND a file log is created so I don't understand why it doesn't work with data_ingestion.py